# Xamarin Android: Resource android: style/AppTheme.Base Not Found

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio, xamarin

I'm new to Xamarin Android development.
I'm following the Microsoft Splash Screen tutorial: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/user-interface/splash-screen

I have got the error saying The AppTheme.Base not found

```
<resources>
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
<style name="MyTheme" parent="AppTheme.Base"></style>
<style name="MyTheme.Splash" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
   <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/splash_screen</item>
   <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
   <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
   <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
   <item name="android:windowActionBar">true</item>
</style>
```

Comment: could it work ?

Answer (score 1):

If you look in the sample they link at the bottom of the page you link to, you can see that they have changed the naming a bit in their resource file. They also switch the names out later in the doc, which is a bit confusing. https://github.com/xamarin/monodroid-samples/blob/master/SplashScreen/SplashActivity/Resources/values/style.xml

You should be able to simply change `AppTheme` to `AppTheme.Base` in the XML you've shown and it should work. Given that you use `MyTheme` in your Application node in the AndroidManifest and `MyTheme.Splash` in your SplashActivity.

Comment: I tried with AppTheme.Base and Visual studio keep throwing AppThem.Base not found.

Answer (score 0):

you could try this:

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
   <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
   <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
   <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
   <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
<style name="MyTheme" parent="AppTheme"></style>
<style name="MyTheme.Splash" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
   <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/splash_screen</item>
   <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
   <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
   <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
   <item name="android:windowActionBar">true</item>
</style>
```

then use `@style/MyTheme`